# The token from the Next Auth middleware always returns null

Tags: authentication, next.js, callback, jwt, next-auth

I believe I've written the code correctly, but even after logging in, the token keeps returning null and I'm redirected back to the signin page. When I check the cookies, it seems like the token is being generated correctly, so I'm not sure what the problem is.

```js
import { withAuth, NextRequestWithAuth } from 'next-auth/middleware'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export default withAuth(
  // `withAuth` augments your `Request` with the user's token.
  function middleware(request: NextRequestWithAuth) {
    console.log('pathname: ', request.nextUrl.pathname)
    console.log('request.nextauth.token', request.nextauth.token)

    if (!request.nextauth.token) {
      return NextResponse.redirect('http://localhost:3000/login')
    }

  },
  {
    callbacks: {
      authorized: ({ token, req }) => {
        console.log('token:', !!token, token)
        return !!token
      },
    },
  },
)

export const config = { matcher: ['/admin', '/'] }
```

```
import { NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import GithubProvider from 'next-auth/providers/github'
import EmailProvider from 'next-auth/providers/email'
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
import { PrismaAdapter } from '@auth/prisma-adapter'
import { compare } from 'bcrypt'
import prisma from './db'

export const authOptions = {
  secret: process.env.NEXT_AUTH_SECRET,
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: 'Credentials',
      credentials: {
        email: { label: 'Email', type: 'email' },
        password: { label: 'Password', type: 'password' },
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials.password) {
          throw new Error('Please enter an email and password')
        }

        const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
          where: {
            email: credentials.email,
          },
        })

        if (!user || !user?.password) {
          throw new Error('No user found')
        }

        const isValid = await compare(credentials.password, user.password)

        if (!isValid) {
          throw new Error('Invalid password')
        }

        if (user) {
          return user
        }
        return null
      },
    }),
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
    EmailProvider({
      server: {
        host: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_HOST,
        port: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PORT,
        auth: {
          user: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_USER,
          pass: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER_PASSWORD,
        },
      },
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, account }) {
      if (user) {
        
        return {
          ...token,
          id: account?.id ? account.id : user.id,
          accessToken: account?.access_token,
          role: user.role,
        }
      }
      return token
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      return {
        ...session,
        user: {
          ...session.user,
          id: token.id,
          name: token.name,
          accessToken: token.accessToken ? token.accessToken : null,
          role: token.role,
        },
      }
    },
  },
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt',
  },
  // debug: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
} satisfies NextAuthOptions
```

So, I referred to the documentation and tried using just a simple piece of code, but the result was the same. If you have any other questions or need further clarification, please let me know.

```
export { default } from "next-auth/middleware";
export const config = { matcher: ['/admin', '/'] };
```